# Collate all entries from one table that don't exist in another in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following formula in the 'Available Staff' sheet:

```
=LET(AvailabilityCalc,FILTER(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl,    IF(ISBLANK($I$11),1,(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Role]=$I$11))*IF(ISBLANK($I$8),1,(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employee]=$I$8))*IF(ISBLANK($I$14),1,(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Discipline]=$I$14))*   (AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[End Date]<$I$2)*(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl),1,0),TRANSPOSE(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[End Date]>TRANSPOSE(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[End Date]))*(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employee]=TRANSPOSE(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employee]))*(1)))-MMULT((TRANSPOSE(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employee])=AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employee])+0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl),1,1,0))+1=0)),IFERROR(SORT(INDEX(AvailabilityCalc,SEQUENCE(ROWS(AvailabilityCalc)),{1,4,5,9}),4),""))
```

[image: Available Staff]

that sits in A2 and pulls in all staff that are available after a specific date defined in I2. This unfortunately has an issue as it pulls the data from the staff that have been allocated to a project previously from a 'Staff Project Allocation' sheet and doesn't incorporate the staff from the 'Staff Details' sheet that are yet to be allocated to a project.

The 'Staff Project Allocation' sheet :

[image: Staff Project Allocation]

The 'Staff Details' sheet :

[image: Staff Details]

Someone kindly helped me with the above function and I'm not sure how to modify it to do what I want. Could it be simpler to keep the above as is and create a new set of data to the right of it say, that pulls in the entries from the 'Staff Details' sheet that don't appear in the data created by the formula and are available from the date specified - whilst also being a development role, which I can do by checking their discipline against another table? Or is there a way to modifiy the formula above to incoporate the data? Something I also need to incorporate in the above function, which I overlooked originally, is to exclude any staff member that has had their employment terminated as noted in the Employment Status columns, so any suggestions on how to incoporate this too would be greatly appreciated.

I'm also starting to wonder whether a VBA solution maywell be a better approach, thoughts?

**Edit 1**

Adjusted function based on the suggestions from Max below. This now includes the ability to filter based on the employment status.

```
=LET(
staff, AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl,
employee, AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employee],
role, AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Role],
discipline, AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Discipline],
endDate, AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[End Date],
employmentStatus, AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employment Status],
rowCt, ROWS(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl),
roleSelection, $I$11,
employeeSelection, $I$8,
disciplineSelection, $I$14,
availableFromDate, $I$2,
empStatusSelection,"Employment Terminated",
mmult_1, MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,rowCt,1,0),TRANSPOSE(endDate>TRANSPOSE(endDate))*(employee=TRANSPOSE(employee))*(1)),
mmult_2, MMULT((TRANSPOSE(employee)= employee)+0,SEQUENCE(rowCt,1,1,0)),
roleCondition, IF(ISBLANK(roleSelection),1,(role=roleSelection)),
employeeCondition, IF(ISBLANK(employeeSelection),1,( employee=employeeSelection)),
disciplineCondition, IF(ISBLANK(disciplineSelection),1,(discipline=disciplineSelection)),
empStatusCondition, NOT(employmentStatus=empStatusSelection),

AvailabilityCalc,FILTER(staff,roleCondition*employeeCondition*disciplineCondition*empStatusCondition*(endDate<availableFromDate)*(TRANSPOSE(mmult_1)-mmult_2+1=0)),

IFERROR(SORT(INDEX(AvailabilityCalc,SEQUENCE(ROWS(AvailabilityCalc)),{1,4,5,10}),4),"")
)
```

**Edit 2**

I now have two tables, one from the Staff Details sheet, showing all staff who are development staff and still employed, this can be seen on the left in the following image (note this all staff allocated to a project or not) and defined by `=FILTER(FILTER(StaffDetailsTbl,(StaffDetailsTbl[Employment Status]<>"Employment Terminated")*(StaffDetailsTbl[Dev Role]="Yes")),{1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0})`, and a separate table defined by the Let function above in edit 1, showing all staff allocated to a project that are available based on a specified date, see table on the right.

[image: Both Tables]

I'd now like to merge the table on the left into the table on the right whilst also removing any duplicate entries. Would the most logical first step to be to adjust the filter for the left table to exclude entries that are in the right table? Then look to merge the two in to the right table somehow? Or is it possible to take the Filter defining the left most table and work it directly in to the function defining the right table?

**Edit 3**
The following function now filters out the entries from the StaffDetailsTbl Table that don't exist in the AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl Table:

```
=FILTER(FILTER(StaffDetailsTbl,(StaffDetailsTbl[Employment Status]<>"Employment Terminated")*(StaffDetailsTbl[Dev Role]="Yes")*(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(StaffDetailsTbl[Employee], AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl, 1, FALSE)),1,0 ))),{1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0})
```

Giving the resulting table on the left for staff not allocated to a project and those allocated to a project and who are available after a specified date on the right:

[image: Staff Not Allocated To A Project]

I now need to figure out how to merge the filter formula from the left table in to the Let function above, or alternatively, build another table from the two that supports all the roleSelection, employeeSelection, disciplineSelection and availableFromDate functionality. Any thoughts on the best way I can do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula logic is complex enough that it's unlikely someone here would be able to invest the time required to work through this on their own.  It means someone has to "reverse engineer" the meaning of every reference, like "what does $I$11 really represent".

While not technically an answer, I can provide some help on how to simplify the problem, and then document the logic for your future reference.  This won't meet the technical definition of a "proper" StackOverflow answer, but it's too much to fit in a comment and still better than leaving you empty-handed.

**Use LET to simplify**

You already have it, so let's go further with it, so we can simplify the formula as much as possible.  Here's one example of using LET to further break down the formula, and using alt-Enter to create non-breaking returns in the excel formula:

```
=LET(
staff, AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl,
emp, AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employee],
role, AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Role],
disc, AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Discipline],
endDate, AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[End Date],
rowCt, ROWS(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl),
mmult_1, MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,rowCt,1,0),TRANSPOSE(endDate>TRANSPOSE(endDate))*(emp=TRANSPOSE(emp))*(1)),
mmult_2, MMULT((TRANSPOSE(emp)=emp)+0,SEQUENCE(rowCt,1,1,0)),
roleCondition, IF(ISBLANK($I$11),1,(role=$I$11)),
empCondition, IF(ISBLANK($I$8),1,(emp=$I$8)),
discCondition, IF(ISBLANK($I$14),1,(disc=$I$14)),

AvailabilityCalc,FILTER(staff,roleCondition*empCondition*discCondition*(endDate<$I$2)*(TRANSPOSE(mmult_1)-mmult_2+1=0)),

IFERROR(SORT(INDEX(AvailabilityCalc,SEQUENCE(ROWS(AvailabilityCalc)),{1,4,5,9}),4),"")
)
```

This is still a *lot* to take in, but it separates the complexity of how we found/calculated the inputs from the actual Filter and Result logic at the end.  if it was my sheet I'd go further and break the formulas down even more, like giving $I$8 or "transpose(emp)=emp+0" a name as well.  The more granular, the better.

**Then Document your LET formula right in excel**

On another sheet, create an Excel table that documents the LET parameters:

| Name | Equates to | Which means |
| --- | --- | --- |
| disc | AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Discipline] | Discipline Col of Staff Table |
| roleCondition | IF(ISBLANK($I$11),1,(role=$I$11)) | Role from I11, or 1 if I11 is blank |
| xyz | $I$11 | describe what I11 is |

I put "xyz" in row 3, but the point is to give a name to each thing, if you are not using name manager.

Hope this helps, either to add clarity for you, or to get someone else started creating a full answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Max. I think I’m going to at least take a look at your suggestion of breaking it down like this to determine how to incorporate excluding entries if the Employment Status is terminated. I think I’ll look to create a separate table for those new starters who are not included on the Available Staff sheet and then look to merge the two somehow.

Comment: @AutomationMonkey If you have control over the data structures, sometimes the best way to solve a problem of this complexity is with at least one helper column.  Each row can have one cell that has flat information about the kinds of lookups it should be included in.  For instance, the cell may contain “CMLTR” where each letter stands for a group that record should be included.  If an employee record has a termination date, then the cell’s formula turns on “T” with no human intervention of any kind except entering the date.  More of the logic is in the row and less in your lookup.

Comment: Hi @Max, I added more Let definitions then added a condition to initially filter out those employees who are terminated. I added `employmentStatus, AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employment Status],` with `empStatusCondition, employmentStatus=NOT(”Employment Terminated”),` and then added the employmentStatusCondition to the AvailabilityCalc `AvailabilityCalc,FILTER(staff,roleCondition*employeeCondition*disciplineCondition*empStatusCondition*(endDate<availableFromDate)*(TRANSPOSE(mmult_1)-mmult_2+1=0)),`. The Condition didn't work, if I change NOT(”Employment Terminated”) to 1 it does. Any idea?

Comment: When I say it does work, I mean it doesn’t just show an empty set of data, it effectively eliminates the condition

Comment: One of the neat things about LET is the ability to easily debug, so use your LET to do the work of revealing the problem.  The LET is a series of variable assignments, followed by one statement that is the formula for the result.  That result can be anything in the LET.  So in place of the final "IFERROR(... result, instead place simply `employmentStatus` and the LET will return that spilled array.  The LET allows you to easily display the result of ANY of your variable definitions.

Comment: Hi @Max, I've edited the question above with the latest function with the EmploymentStatus added. I've tried using F9 to debug the different sections. `AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employment Status]` but when I use it to evaluate anything else related to the status it just gives a #NAME?. For example, when selecting `empStatusCondition, employmentStatus=NOT(”Employment Terminated”)` and pressing F9 it gives #NAME?. Is there anything else I can do to determine what's going on?

Comment: ‘employmentStatus=NOT(“Employment Terminated”) is *not* a valid condition.  NOT must be applied to a condition that is either true or false.  Whatever is inside the () *must* result in wait her true, ro false.  In your LET:  ‘empStatusCondition, NOT(employmentStatus=“Employee terminated”),` is the correct way.

Comment: Awesome, just figured it was the NOT, thanks for the fix

Comment: Also, wasn’t sure if you saw my comment above about how to use your LET functions for debugging.  Once you get used to LET, you’ll never go back to the old way.

Comment: Hi @Max, I've now got a separate table with all development staff who are still employed and wish to remove any entries that are in the table defined by the Let function - I have added details as a second edit to my question. Do you know what the best approach might be?

Comment: Hi @Max, I now have a solution to remove the entries showing in the other table and wish to find a solution to integrate the filter used for the table on the left in to the table on the right, so merging the two tables, yet retainng the functionality of the table on the right. I have included more details in edit 3 above, .Any ideas on the best way to approach this?

Comment: @AutomationMonkey This is sliding from needing help with one specific roadblock to needing ongoing development support, which is outside the scope of StackExchange.  I would advise caution, you are continuing to add additional complexity into a solution that is already on your "complexity horizon."  A better approach is to simplify the existing logic before adding any additional logic.  For instance, a single employee table with a flag for terminated employees is fundamentally less complex than comparing data between two tables, which will *always* mean longer, more complex formulas.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I do have a table of staff with the flag you mention. I’ll keep working on simplifying the Let and see if I can integrate the filter for the staff not included.